# WCF The semaphore timeout period has expired

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an asp.net application (3.5) that connect to a WCF service using http binding. The service does some kind of  serialization to Xml and on some servers we get the following:

> Exception Type: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, An
>   unhandled WCF error was thrown.
>
> Message: The semaphore timeout period has expired at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputAsyncStream.ByteBuffer.WaitForWriteComplete()
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputAsyncStream.NextBuffer()

Any idea? 
Can it be related to problems